# center align the Pagination Links in display tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I want to align the display tag pagination links 1,2,3, etc and [prev][first] etc default provided. When I wrap the `<div align="center">`, the links and page numbers align in center. But, it rises as some issues in aligning across different browsers.

Is there any way that just ***align center the default pagination and links in display tag***?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the HTML `<center>` tag?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

if you want to put it inside a `<display>` tag, I think you could do this too....

`<display:column <center> blah blah </center> </display:column>`